# How to obtain the same varimax-rotated PCA results in MATLAB and SPSS?

Tags: pca, spss, matlab, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I'm trying to perform a PCA Extraction + Varimax Rotation in MATLAB and obtain the same results as in SPSS.

My data is the following matrix **A**:

```
var1  var2  var3
----------------
10    7     3
3     10    8
8     2     6
```

This is the syntax I used in SPSS:

```
FACTOR
/VARIABLES var1 var2 var3
/MISSING LISTWISE 
/ANALYSIS var1 var2 var3
/PRINT EXTRACTION ROTATION
/CRITERIA FACTORS(3) ITERATE(100)
/EXTRACTION PC
/CRITERIA ITERATE(25)
/ROTATION VARIMAX
/METHOD=CORRELATION.
```

I have no problems to find the eigeinvalues and the variances using:

```
[V,D] = eig(corr(A));
eig_total = diag(D); % Eigeinvalues
var_exp = D./sum(D); % Percentage of variance
cum_var = cumsum(var_exp); % Cumulative variance
% is there a way to obtain the same resuluts using the pca function?
```

[image]

However, I don't know how to obtain these tables:

[image]

I've tried the following code, but none of them give me the same results:

```
rotated_solution1 = rotatefactors(V)
rotated_solution2 = rotatefactors(pca(A))
```

Comment: Did you google `matlab factor analysis`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/factoran.html

Comment: @ttnphns Yes I did, however this function is based on maximum likelihood estimate, it is not perfoming a PCA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor analysis rotates loadings, not eigenvectors; see my answer here for a lengthy discussion: [Is PCA followed by a rotation (such as varimax) still PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612)

Your `V` are eigenvectors, and loadings are given by `V*sqrt(D)`, so what you need to do is `rotatefactors(V*sqrt(D))`. But it's better to make sure that the zero column of `V` is kicked out, otherwise Matlab seems to run into some numerical issues.

Here is the code:

```c
%// PCA
[V,D] = eig(corr(A));

%// Sorting the eigenvectors/eigenvalues
[~, ind] = sort(diag(D), 'descend');
D = D(ind, ind);
V = V(:, ind);

%// Keeping only the first two (non-zero ones)
D = D(1:2,1:2);
V = V(:,1:2);

%// Computing loadings
L = V*sqrt(D);

%// Rotating loadings
L_rotated = rotatefactors(L);
```

Now `L` is

```
    0.9950   -0.1001
   -0.6617   -0.7497
   -0.8970    0.4420
```

and `L_rotated` is

```
    0.9072    0.4208
   -0.1874   -0.9823
   -0.9971   -0.0767
```

the same as in SPSS. Note that the column signs are arbitrary, see here: [Does the sign of scores or of loadings in PCA or FA have a meaning? May I reverse the sign?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880)

P.S. Answering your question from the comments: I don't think there is a built-in function in Matlab that would do all of that.

Comment: One should also take care of the option "Kaiser normalization" in SPSS as default for Varimax. (which should be indifferent only if all pc's are used for rotation). I don't know how matlab does handle this...