# Different tools for calculating PCA

Tags: pca, scikit-learn

I have a test csv file and I have written a code via [Scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html) to show the PCA for that. I also use another tool in Excel ([XLSTAT](https://help.xlstat.com/s/article/principal-component-analysis-pca-in-excel?language=en_US)) to compare the results.
The XLSTAT automatically calculates the number of features, however, based on my understanding, I have to specify how many components are needed using the scikit package. For example, while XLSTAT shows 5 features:

```
Factor scores:
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5
A1 -1.293 -0.663 -0.462 -0.713 0.010
A2 -0.297 0.293 -1.429 0.397 0.056
A3 2.328 0.069 0.987 -0.108 0.062
A4 -0.556 -2.273 0.538 0.344 -0.032
A5 1.823 0.775 -0.597 -0.052 -0.085
A6 -2.005 1.799 0.963 0.133 -0.011
```

In the following code, I specified 2 components:

```
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
print( principalComponents )

[[-1.29292842 0.66325508] [-0.29706395 -0.29346337] [ 2.32751305 -0.06850045] [-0.5558091 2.27288988] [ 1.82312052 -0.77527304] [-2.0048321 -1.7989081 ]]
```

As you can see, the first column in XLSTAT and scikit are the same. However, the second columns are negated. For example, considering F1 and F2, we see

```
XLSTAT => -1.293 -0.663
scikit =>  [-1.29292842 0.66325508]
```

Considering the F1 and F2 as a XY scatter point, I want to know why the value of Y in XLSTAT and scikit are opposite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the sign of scores or of loadings in PCA or FA have a meaning? May I reverse the sign?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA will [give you the eigenvectors of the empirical covariance matrix of your data.](http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2020/cs229-notes10.pdf) Then, the sign of a particular eigenvalue doesn't matter, which has been addressed [here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205713/does-the-sign-of-eigenvectors-matter) As a brief recap, let $\Sigma$ be the empirical covariance matrix of your data; suppose we have some vector $v$ such that the exists some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\Sigma v = \lambda v$ (def. of eigenvector/eigenvalue). Let $w = -v$; then $w$ is also an eigenvector of $\Sigma$, as $\Sigma w = -\lambda w$. From a non-rigorous standpoint, all you've done is "flip" the eigenvector, meaning that the corresponding principal component is essentially the same. For a more in-depth explanation, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers).

Thus, mathematically, both of the implementations above are equivalent and valid. I'm not sure how XLSTAT and scikit implement PCA internally, but different implementations can certainly lead to this behavior.