# What is the mean of negative sign in PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I used PCA to project 4 dimensions to 2 dimensions. All the values were positive, but PCA gave me negative values.

I wonder if the negative only means correlates negatively with the axis.

Comment: This has been asked and [answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers).