# Why am I getting different PCA loadings for the same data set using two different r packages?

Tags: r, pca

I have applied PCA to a dataset using two different R packages viz. "stats" and "FactoMineR". For both models, I am getting different loadings. What may be the probable reason behind such a difference?

---

```
prcomp {stats}

Rotation (n x k) = (6 x 6):

            PC1        PC2         
THN   0.5597064 -0.1736148  

GRH    0.5289944 -0.2447140 

SRD   -0.4187044 -0.2400785 

THML  -0.2361008 -0.5718485
  
GLI    0.3308003  0.4284650 

GRMA   0.2576972 -0.5845873
```

---

```
PCA {FactoMineR}

$coord

          Dim.1      Dim.2       
THN   0.9569614  0.2603887
 
GRH   0.9044514  0.3670237
  
SRD  -0.7158823  0.3600715
  
THML -0.4036748  0.8576624 

GLI   0.5655878 -0.6426149
  
GRMA  0.4405993  0.8767682
```

---

```
#PCA using stats
myPr <- prcomp(my_data[,-1], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
myPr

#PCA using FactoMineR 
library(FactoMineR)
pr <- PCA(my_data[,-1], scale.unit = TRUE, graph = TRUE)
pr$var
```

```
#Data subset
my_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      Genotype = c(
        "BHIMA",
        "BHIMA",
        "BHIMA",
        "BHIMA",
        "BHIMA",
        "NSDG",
        "NSDG",
        "NSDG",
        "NSDG",
        "NSDG",
        "NSLG",
        "NSLG",
        "NSLG",
        "NSLG",
        "NSLG"
      ),
      THN = c(
        4.875,
        5.75,
        5,
        3.75,
        3.66666666666667,
        9.0625,
        10.7,
        7.52941176470588,
        8,
        12,
        4.25,
        3.66666666666667,
        5.2,
        6,
        5.25
      ),
      GRH = c(
        102.4643125,
        124.635333333333,
        95.4393888888889,
        77.5246666666667,
        74.8633111111111,
        188.138770833333,
        170.288916666667,
        142.064431372549,
        152.74425,
        226.286,
        86.3530833333333,
        80.1745555555556,
        109.171533333333,
        134.698666666667,
        122.7548
      ),
      SRD = c(
        20.9620954613095,
        21.72740625,
        18.9397321428571,
        21.9752083333333,
        19.768965,
        20.6400036051417,
        17.4263925682651,
        18.8010196737519,
        18.8909826388889,
        18.6996699829932,
        20.685875,
        21.2876111111111,
        21.0639923809524,
        22.5462371428571,
        23.3662583333333
      ),
      THML = c(
        365.522017936508,
        336.32533125,
        343.027892857143,
        365.968166666667,
        352.466585,
        380.315924009015,
        438.888573775299,
        384.717647703081,
        376.74879890873,
        357.975157908163,
        481.1476125,
        497.496111111111,
        599.674862857143,
        694.572626666667,
        545.377958333333
      ),
      GLI = c(
        0.0962519040291448,
        0.185481840453265,
        0.210969297714791,
        0.127273546499529,
        0.128791133588149,
        0.104009842530975,
        0.105509742573322,
        0.0932643040680137,
        0.0952753840583971,
        0.214037130114979,
        0.0414932567676607,
        0.0429400045716451,
        0.0735321530011779,
        0.0355329427205008,
        0.0458192673112064
      ),
      GRMA = c(
        0.04171768575,
        0.0463768018,
        0.039131903,
        0.0427794242,
        0.0327366384,
        0.082782452375,
        0.0812153345833334,
        0.0690879901764706,
        0.065846674625,
        0.0885941995714286,
        0.04575302325,
        0.0408745306666667,
        0.0792771544,
        0.1083637692,
        0.0836376916
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-15L)
  )
```

Comment: Check this SO post: [PCA from FactoMineR::PCA() not returning same as base::prcomp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298385/pca-from-factominerpca-not-returning-same-as-baseprcomp).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The values you get from FactoMineR are not loadings: they are coordinates. Loadings are coordinates divided by the square root of eigenvalues.

I don't know if you can directly get loadings from FactoMineR. However, you can retrieve eigenvalues (in your example, through `pr$eig`), so you can calculate loadings from coordinates.

Example with your data, for the first dimension of the PCA:

```
library(FactoMineR) 
pr <- PCA(my_data[,-1], 
          scale.unit = TRUE,
          graph = TRUE) 
res = pr$var$coord[,"Dim.1"] / sqrt( pr$eig["comp 1","eigenvalue"])

res

    THN        GRH        SRD       THML        GLI       GRMA 
 0.5597064  0.5289944 -0.4187044 -0.2361008  0.3308003  0.2576972
```

-- which is in line with your results from prcomp, so there is no inconsistency between the two libraries (at least in this respect):

```
myPr <- prcomp(my_data[,-1], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
myPr$rotation[,"PC1"]
     THN        GRH        SRD       THML        GLI       GRMA 
 0.5597064  0.5289944 -0.4187044 -0.2361008  0.3308003  0.2576972
```

---

Edit: After digging a bit, it is in fact possible to directly get loadings from the factoMineR package without resorting to the above code (I leave it as it is though, to illustrate the underlying calculations). In the data from the original question, you can find the loadings in `pr$svd$V`.

Comment: I have retrieved the loadings for the second dimension which is also in line with the `prcomp` result. The only difference that still remains is the same sign on the numbers. So should I ignore this fact and proceed further? because only the direction will be altered and not the relative difference. Which one should I prefer, `prcomp` or `FactoMineR`?

Comment: @ChaitanyaBorkar These answers should answer your own question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258885/pca-scores-for-only-the-first-principal-components-are-of-wrong-sign  . (In short, the question of differing signs is not really a problem, so you can use one or the other library). By the way, in the meantime, I found out how to directly get loadings from factoMineR, try: `pr$svd$V`.

Comment: **Thank you very much.** My doubts are clear in this aspect.

Answer (score 11):

Principal components are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. Eigenvectors are only defined up to a multiplicative constant. In this case, both results are identical up to a multiplicative constant:

```
> x <- c(0.5597064, 0.5289944, -0.4187044, -0.2361008, 0.3308003, 0.2576972)
> y <- c(0.9569614, 0.9044514, -0.7158823, -0.4036748, 0.5655878, 0.4405993)
> abs(cor(x,y))
[1] 1
```

The result of `prcomp` is normalized to Euclidean length one, the result of `FactoMiner` not:

```
> sqrt(sum(x^2))
[1] 1
> sqrt(sum(y^2))
[1] 1.709756
```